# Find objects that depend on a sp

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use Microsoft SQL server. I have a db with hundreds of Stored Procedures. To find the dependencies, I can right click the SP, select view dependencies, and click `objects that depend on [name]`.

I have this query to find all the stored procs

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'procedure'
```

and if I add this, I exclude every single system SP.

```
and LEFT(routine_name, 3) not in ('sp_','xp_','ms_')`
```

I would like to find ALL the SPs that no other proc/function/trigger depends on.
Ex: I have `sproc1`. In the right click + view dependencies I have at `objects that depend on [sproc1]` no elements, meaning that nothing depends on this SP.

Using a query to find procs that were unaltered for a year or more is not an option since some operations execute every leap year. Is there a way to write a query to determine the name of the stored proc and schema_id **only** for the stored procs that NOONE depend on? (having zero objects that depend on [this_sp] )

Answer (score 0):

You can modify list of searched objects below:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies e
    WHERE e.referenced_id = o.object_id
)
AND o.type IN (N'V', N'P', N'TF', N'IF', N'FN')
```